# Progressive Web App With .NET Core and .cshtml Files

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, service-worker

Hello I am trying to turn my Angular 2+ application into a progressive web app and am running into some issues and am not sure if I am using my service worker correctly.  I have 2 main questions on how I should be setting this up.

First, I am seeing the following error in my console and not sure what I need to change to get the correct URL for the "starturl"...

> Site cannot be installed: no matching service worker detected. You may
>   need to reload the page, or check that the service worker for the
>   current page also controls the start URL from the manifest

Here is my plugin in webpack (this seems to be generating my manifest.json correctly I just am not sure what I should be using as the start_url). I pulled this example from a Google Developers blog.  All my application resouces (service-worker.js, manifest.js, bundled js/css) is going into a dist folder.

```
new ManifestPlugin({
    fileName: 'manifest.json',
    seed: {
        name: "Angular Testing",
        short_name: "Angular Testing",
        theme_color: "#b92b27",
        background_color: "#ffffff",
        display: "standalone",
        orientation: "portrait",
        start_url: "./?utm_source=web_app_manifest",
        icons: [
            {
                src: "../../icons/android-chrome-192x192.png",
                sizes: "192x192",
                type: "image\/png"
            },
            {
                src: "../../icons/android-chrome-256x256.png",
                sizes: "256x256",
                type: "image\/png"
            },
            {
                src: "../../icons/android-chrome-256x256.png",
                type: "image/png",
                sizes: "512x512"
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

I have tried a combination of different start_urls but nothing has got rid of that error in the console and I cannot install the application.

My second issue is not understanding if I am caching my service-worker resources correctly. In all the examples everyone has a Index.html file that is in the root of their project but in my .NET Core application I have my _Layout.cshtml and my Index.cshtml which make up the entry for the application.

```
new SWPrecacheWebpackPlugin({
    navigateFallback: '/Home/Index',
    staticFileGlobs: [
        '/',
        '/Home/Index.cshtml',
        '/Home/Index',
        '/Shared/_Layout',
        'wwwroot/dist/**.js',
        'wwwroot/dist/**.css',
        'wwwroot/dist/**.png'
    ],
    mergeStaticsConfig: true, // if you don't set this to true, you won't see any webpack-emitted assets in your serviceworker config 
    staticFileGlobsIgnorePatterns: [/\.map$/], // use this to ignore sourcemap files 
})
```

I have configured my service worker to be generated using the above plugin in webpack but I am not sure how I should be specifying my Index.cshtml so be sure it gets cached.

When I look in my "Cache Storage" under the console I am not seeing some of the files I would expect to be cached including any of the cshtml files.  Is there something special I need to do to get this working?

[image: Cache Storage Screenshot]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I do not know what's in your _Layout.cshtml and Index.cshtml file but there is probably some code which have to be rendered serverside (razor, tag helpers...) So this shouldn't be cached clientside. But you can cache the fully rendered site which in your example is probably available under http://localhost:5001 or http://localhost:5001/Home depending on your defined serverside routing.

Comment: Hi Same problem for me.If u got solution,pls help me

Comment: @dev53,have u got solution.if means,pls help me

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem and solved by adding

```
   services.AddProgressiveWebApp(new PwaOptions
  {
    CacheId = "Worker 1.1",
    Strategy = ServiceWorkerStrategy.CacheFirst,
    RoutesToPreCache = "/Home/Index, /Shared/_Layout,/Shared/Error",

    OfflineRoute = "index.html",
  });
```

in  the method public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {} in startup.cs file using "using WebEssentials.AspNetCore.Pwa;" namespace

then added manifest.json in wwwroot

```
 {
"name": "Awesome Application",
 "short_name": "Awesome",
 "description": "The most awesome application in the world",
 "icons": [
{
  "src": "/img/android-chrome-192x192.png",
  "sizes": "192x192"
},
{
  "src": "/img/android-chrome-512x512.png",
  "sizes": "512x512"
},
{
  "src": "/favicon.ico"

}
],
"display": "standalone",
"start_url": "/"
}
```

pls refer this link

https://github.com/madskristensen/WebEssentials.AspNetCore.ServiceWorker

Its working fine for me

Thanks